# D3 chart and json

Tags: json, elasticsearch, d3.js

i want to graph of data useing D3 linechart 
eventhough it contains data by a format of jsonarray, but it isn't shown graph
How do I put data into it?

1. real data capture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c96UY.png)
2. console err log [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxsO1.png)

   ```
   <select name="sel" id="que">
     <option ng-repeat="x in data" selected> {{x}}</option>
   </select> <br/>
   <input type="text" id="tm1"/> 날짜(From) <br/>
   <input type="text" id="tm2"/> 날짜(To) <br/>
   <SELECT name="sel2" id="fd" multiple>

     <option value="DATE">시간</option>
     <option value="KW">KW</option>
     <option value="KVAR">KVAR</option>
     <option value="FOpress">FOpress</option>
     <option value="LOpress">LOpress</option>
     <option value="FOtemp">FOtemp</option>
     <option value="HTtemp">HTtemp</option>
     <option value="LOtemp">LOtemp</option>
     <option value="CWtemp">CWtemp</option>


   </select>
   <input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="submit()" /> <br/><br/>
   ```

   DATE 
              KW 
              KVAR 
              FOpress 
              LOpress 
              FOtemp 
              HTtemp 
              LOtemp 
              CWtemp

   ```
   <tr ng-repeat="x in hits track by $index">

         <td ng-if = "x._source.DATE !== NULL "> {{x._source.DATE}} </td>
         <td ng-if = "x._source.KW !== NULL "> {{x._source.KW}} </td>
         <td ng-if = "x._source.KVAR !== NULL "> {{x._source.KVAR}} </td>
         <td ng-if = "x._source.FOpress !== NULL "> {{x._source.FOpress}} </td>
         <td ng-if = "x._source.LOpress !== NULL "> {{x._source.LOpress}} </td>
         <td ng-if = "x._source.FOtemp !== NULL "> {{x._source.FOtemp}} </td>
         <td ng-if = "x._source.HTtemp !== NULL "> {{x._source.HTtemp}} </td>
         <td ng-if = "x._source.LOtemp !== NULL "> {{x._source.LOtemp}} </td>
         <td ng-if = "x._source.CWtemp !== NULL "> {{x._source.CWtemp}} </td>

    </tr>
   ```

   {{xa._source}}

   ```
   <input type="button" value="graph" ng-click="graph()" /> <br/><br/>

   <div class="container">
     <div class="jumbotron">
     </div>
   </div>
   <br />
   <svg id="visualisation" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
   ```

   ```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['elasticsearch']);



   // Create the es service from the esFactory


   myApp.service('es', function (esFactory) {
       return esFactory({ host: 'http://localhost:9200'});
   });

   myApp.controller('ServerHealthController', function($scope, es, esFactory) {

       es.cat.indices(function (err, resp) {
           if (err) {
               $scope.data = err.message;

           } else {
               var i = 12;
               var j = 0;
               var k = 25;
               var l = 0;
               var indexlist = new Array();
               var id = new Array();
               var idlist = new Array();

               while (j < resp.length ){
                 idlist[j] = resp[j];
                 j++;
               }


               while (true){

                 k++;

                   while (idlist[i] !== " "){

                     indexlist[j] = idlist[i];

                     i++;
                     j++;

                   }



                 if(idlist[k] == "\n")
                 {
                   i = k + 13;
                   k = k + 30;
                   indexlist.length = j;
                   id[l] = indexlist.join('');

                   l++;
                   j=0;
                 }

                 if(k > idlist.length)
                 {
                   break;
                 }



               }



               $scope.data = id;

           }
       });
   });

   // We define an Angular controller that returns query results,
   // Inputs: $scope and the 'es' service


   myApp.controller('QueryController', function($scope, es, esFactory) {

     $scope.graph = function() {
       var table1 = document.getElementById("list2");

       var i=0;
       var arr=new Array();
       var data=new Array();
       while(i<table1.rows.length)
       {
         arr[i] = table1.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
         data.push(arr[i]);
         i++;

       }
       i=0;
       var Mdate=new Array();
       var table = document.getElementById("list");
       while(i<table.rows.length)
       {
         Mdate[i] = table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
         i++;
       }



       console.log(data + Mdate[1] + Mdate[Mdate.length-1])

       var timeFormat = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');

       var mindate = timeFormat.parse(Mdate[1].trim().replace(' ', 'T')),
           maxdate = timeFormat.parse(Mdate[Mdate.length-1].trim().replace(' ', 'T'));

       var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
         WIDTH = 2500,
         HEIGHT = 500,
         MARGINS = {
           top: 20,
           right: 20,
           bottom: 20,
           left: 50
         },
         xScale = d3.time.scale().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([mindate, maxdate]),
         yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0,4000]),
         xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                 .scale(xScale)
                 .ticks(5)
                 .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")),
         yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                 .scale(yScale)
                 .orient("left");

       var aJsonArray = new Array();
       var aJson = new Object();
       var c=0;
       while (c<data.length) {
         aJson = data[c];
         aJsonArray.push(aJson);
         c++;
       }


       var data2 = new Object();
       data2 = [aJsonArray];
       alert(data2);

       data2.forEach(function(d) {
                    [d.DATE] = timeFormat.parse(d.DATE.trim().replace(' ', 'T'));
                    console.log(date2.DATE)
                });


       vis.append("svg:g")
                 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
                 .call(xAxis);
       vis.append("svg:g")
                 .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
                 .call(yAxis);

       var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
         .x(function(d)   {
           return xScale([d.DATE]);
         })
         .y(function(d)   {
           return yScale([d.KW]);
         });

       vis.append('svg:path')
         .attr('d', lineGen(data2))
         .attr('stroke', 'green')
         .attr('stroke-width', 2)
         .attr('fill', 'none');
     }




     $scope.submit = function() {

     var ab = $('#que').val();
     var tm1 = $('#tm1').val();
     var tm2 = $('#tm2').val();
     var fd = $('#fd').val();
     $scope.td = fd;


     if(fd == ""){fd = true}
   //  else {fd = mydate, fd};

     alert(ab+"    "+tm1+"    "+tm2+"    "+fd);
   ```

   // search for documents

   ```
       es.search({
           index: ab,
           body: {
             "query":
               {
                 "bool" : {
                   "must" : {

                     "range" : {
                       "DATE" : {
                         "gte" : tm1,
                         "lte" : tm2,


                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }
               },
               "sort": {"DATE" : {"order":"asc"}},
               "_source": fd,
               size : 60    // Number of documents to show
               }

       }).then(function (response) {
           $scope.hits = response.hits.hits;
           console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.hits))





       }).catch(function (err) {
         if (err.status === 404) {
           alert("error 404" );

         } else {
           alert("error : " + err );

         }
       });
     }

   });
   ```

Comment: Trying to figure out what's going on with this code, but a bit more info could help. Could you provide the value of data2 before data2.forEach call?

Also it looks like you have a typo in your console log within, targetting a field I don't see referenced elsewhere ('date2.DATE').

Also if you could log out "d" within the x line function? Thanks

Comment: @MikeMichaels The value in data2 is same as "1. real data captual "